# MacOS: Manually force a daemon to start

Tags: macos, unix, daemon, launchd

I've created a plist file in the /Library/LaunchDaemon/

The computer on which it runs cannot be restarted (server thing), it's running MacOS Tiger. I expected the following command to do the job, but it states it's not meant to be run directly:

```
launchd /Library/LaunchDaemon/parallel.plist
```

How can this be achieved?
Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/parallel.plist
```

should cause the daemon to autorun.

See
http://www.aandcp.com/launchdaemons-and-mac-os-x-openvpn-as-an-example

Comment: You might find this talk interesting: www.youtube.com/watch?v=mLwn_TbBntI

Answer (score 1):

I know this post already has an answer but because this is such an uncommon topic, I thought I'd weigh in as well. The command that worked for me was

sudo launchctl kickstart system/com.example.service

The plist for this daemon would need to be in /Library/LaunchDaemons.

Comment: I can't really remember why I needed this in a fist place (2011?), but tested on Big Sur (2021) and indeed it works! Cheers.

Comment: Thanks! I actually tested it on Mojave, but good to know it works on Big Sur as well.